# Get an object property name of a a nexted array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm pretty new to JavaScript and am wondering if I do it the correct way.

Consider this object:

```js
const pageLinks = {
    tickets: [
        { to: "/tickets/mytickets", },
        { to: "/tickets/newticket", },
        { to: "/tickets/followup", }
    ],
    home: [
        { to: "/home/dashboard", }
    ],
    about: [
        { to: "/about/author", }
    ]
}
```

When a user requests the route `/tickets/followup` I would like it to return `tickets`. This code, my first one ever, does exactly that:

```js
const to = { path: '/tickets/followup' }

for (let page in pageLinks) {
    let links = pageLinks[page]

    links.forEach(element => {
        if (element.to === to.path) {
            console.log(page)
        }
    });
}
```

My question: is this the correct way of doing it? Or would it be better to use a `filter()` method?

Comment: It seems your data is very straight forward in structure and value, so in that case why don't you just  extract the first token from`/tickets/followup`, which is `tickets`. but in case this is just an example an real data can be different then you have to find it or have to create a hash.

Comment: @KoushikChatterjee Could you give an example on how to extract that?

Comment: what I meant is, what if you don't process the entire data as your input string for query (which is `/tickets/followup`) already contains your output (`tickets`). If you want to extract in that way you can simply do `to.path.split("/")[1]` and that will give you the corresponding result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Amusing each path has one destination page it would be faster to use the paths as keys and pages as values. This way lookup based upon path is simple and fast.

```js
const pageLinks = {
  tickets: [
    { to: "/tickets/mytickets", },
    { to: "/tickets/newticket", },
    { to: "/tickets/followup", }
  ],
  home: [
    { to: "/home/dashboard", }
  ],
  about: [
    { to: "/about/author", }
  ]
};

const routes = {};
for (const page in pageLinks) {
  const links = pageLinks[page];
  links.forEach(link => routes[link.to] = page);
}

console.log(routes);

const to = { path: '/tickets/followup' };
console.log(routes[to.path]);
```

Comment: Creating a hashtable seems like a very nice solution, thank you. When the `to.path` is not found it says `undefined` while my suggestion says nothing. I think the difference doesn't matter.

Comment: @DarkLite1 If you want to avoid the `undefined` (console log) output you should assign the result to a variable and only log it when present. `const page = routes[to.path]` then `if (page) console.log(page)`.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, the "correct way", or the "best way" of doing something is really relative. If your code solves the problem (and it does), it's fine. There are infinite ways of solving the same problem. Other two ways:

Using `Object.keys` and `array.map`:

```
const to = { path: '/tickets/followup' }
Object.keys(pageLinks).map(page => pageLinks[page].map(link => {
    if (link.to == to.path) console.log(page)
}));
```

Using `array.find`:

```
const to = { path: '/tickets/followup' }
let found = Object.keys(pageLinks).find(page => pageLinks[page].find(link => link.to == to.path));
console.log(found);
```

Comment: In your first code block I'd recommend replacing `map` with `forEach`. You currently only use `map` for iteration purposes, which is not where `map` is for. For just iteration `forEach` is less heavy because it doesn't return a newly created array.